# Split a string on multiple blankspaces but not on single?

Tags: vb.net, string, split

I have a string that i need to split where there are 2 or more blankspaces, but i dont want to split it on single blankspace.

For example, a string might look something like this:

> "Name of something   "five blanks"   Name of something else "three blanks"  And so on"

And i need the split to be:

- Name of something
- Name of something else
- And so on

I hope you kan help me

Comment: I found it, i really need to learn regex propperly
    Dim lineSplit As String() = Regex.Replace(line, " {2,}", vbTab).Split(vbTab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you can use RegEx to accomplish that, but that's a bit of overkill.  The String.Split method has an overload that takes an array of strings to use as delimiters:

```
line.Split(New String() {"  "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```